# cleanest way to get a row of values out of openpyxl?

Tags: python, iterator, generator, openpyxl

I've got some code that previously handled .csv files using the [python csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).  As our source material is actually Excel, it would be a lot simpler if we could work directly on the .xlsx files, so I found [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and started playing around with that - it looks like it should do what we need.

Previously, we had a simple/standard block of code that used the csv.reader  and islice to grab one row at a time and assign a bunch of values for each row:

```
with open(csvfile) as f:       
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')
    for row in islice(reader, 28,29):
        [ifile, in_time, dur, day, sess, flight, dive] = row
```

The csv.reader function returns each row as a list of strings, which is what the rest of the program expects (in this case) my local row variable to be.  Openpyxl, however, seems to want to return a generator (which makes sense): I can trivially take that generator, cast all the values to strings, append those strings to a temporary list, and then assign all the original variables to the elements in that temp list.  But it seems to me like there should be a more elegant way - I'm pretty new at this whole python gig but there always seems to be a much cleaner way to do stuff like this.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('tunnel.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_row=4, max_col=7):
    # build a temporary list to store the actual cell values
    my_cell_values = []
    for cell in row:
        my_cell_values.append(str(cell.value))
    [ifile, in_time, dur, day, sess, flight, dive] = my_cell_values
```

Suggestions appreciated here.  It works just fine this way, but it just doesn't quite "look right" to me

Comment: `[ifile, in_time, dur, ...] = [cell.value for cell in row]`

Comment: Use `load_workbook(…, read_only=True)` and `iter_rows(…, values_only=True)` for this kind of work.

Comment: Thanks.  the values_only option is what I was looking for.  If you want to answer with that I'll mark it correct, should you care about such things..  ;-)